# Adstock transform in non advertising varibles

Tags: regression-coefficients, feature-engineering

In Marketing Media Mix models, adstock transformations are commonly seen in advertising variables. However, in other domains where the regression tool is intended to estimate the effect of variables on the output variable, for example price elasticity and demand, when several variables are incorporated, does adstock transformations on other non-advertising variables make sense?

Additionally, I am asking this because one of the advantages of extending the effect without using shifts is to have a single variable instead of a multitude of lags on one, with the advantages that could entail.

Comment: Can you please explain MMM?

Comment: It is an acronym of Marketing media mix modeling.

Comment: As far as I can tell, "Adstock" is warmed-over exponential smoothing for time series.